# reCapctha V3 Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript

I am running a script to get the reCaptcha V3 values to validate a form.

```
<!-- reCaptcha -->
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<?php echo $user::PUBLIC_KEY; ?>'></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo $user::PUBLIC_KEY; ?>', {action: 'login'})
        .then(function(token) {
            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'g-recaptcha-response',
                value: token
            }).prependTo('#login-form');
        });
    });
</script>
```

and I get this in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) null
Promise.then (async)
then @ recaptcha__en.js:512
(anonymous) @ login.php:121
Yb @ recaptcha__en.js:501
UF @ recaptcha__en.js:498
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:513
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:532
```

This only happens on my localhost but not on my shared host.

Comment: Silly me. I forgot that the key checks to match the Domain.

Comment: Dude...all I can say it thank you